# Can I contribute to the Stack Exchange source code?

Tags: discussion

Is the Stack Exchange (or Stack Overflow) website a public repository somewhere like maybe on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub)?

I'd love to help develop any new features or fix bugs. Maybe [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/tour) needs help developing the API?

I'm just looking to see if there is a way I can help/contribute besides answering questions :)

Comment: Some of the code written has been open sourced - see [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchange-open-source-projects/) blog post. You are welcome to contribute there.

Comment: It wouldn't be fully open-source even if it would be fully published, as long as it is compiled using closed-source tools, it's not very likely that M$ would open it's code? Probably you wouldn't like to see anyway :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stack Exchange is a private company so it's unlikely that they'll let you contribute directly to their source code. There are a number of open source projects, some created by Stack Exchange, some used by it that you could contribute to:

Stack Exchange Created:

- [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)
- [SEDE](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer)
- [Markdownsharp](https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/)
- [Pagedown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/)

Used by Stack Exchange:

- [Google Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)
- [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/)
- [Nginx](http://nginx.org/)
- [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/)

See [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

There are plenty of Google Prettify bugs on Meta alone, fixing those would be great :-)!

Comment: And let's not forget Stack Id, Sigil, Exceptional, Booksleeve, Protobuf.NET... see also http://www.sklivvz.com/posts/coding

Comment: :), please feel free to edit/CW the thing @Sklivvz.